# How to append a div to the first <body> tag using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, hierarchy

I was trying to make a quality-of-life script for a game, until i noticed that the buttons i had inserted didnt work. after a bit of searching i had found out that the website had 2 body tags. and that my button was being placed in the second one, rather than the first. is there a way to put an element in the first  tag?

I really couldn't think of any possible solution to this.

this is my code so far:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  console.log(e);
  if ( e.key === "p") {
    asd();
  }
};

var element = document.createElement('style');
element.innerText = style;
document.head.appendChild(element);

const sda = document.createElement("div");
sda.class = "dropdown";
const fasd = document.createElement("button");
fasd.class = "dropbtn";
sda.appendChild(fasd);
const sdf = document.createElement("div");
sdf.id = "myDropdown";
sdf.class = "dropdown-content";
const a1 = document.createElement("a");
const a2 = document.createElement("a");
fasd.appendChild(sdf);
sdf.appendChild(a1);
sdf.appendChild(a2);
const gfd = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
gfd.appendChild(sda);
const pol = document.createTextNode("Taking Over");
a1.appendChild(pol);







function asd() {
  var audio1 = new Audio('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/967213871267971072/1027416621318414406/8mb.video-Vf9-wfenD0dA.m4a');
  audio1.play();
};
/*para.onclick = asd();


document.body.appendChild(para); */

var style = `
#pas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#canvas {
    background-image: linear-gradient( 358.4deg,  rgba(249,151,119,1) -2.1%, rgba(98,58,162,1) 90% );
}
.startMenu {
    color: #000;

}
.startMenuHolder changelogHolder {
    opacity: 0;
}
.startMenuHolder linkHolder {
    opacity: 0;
}
#html {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 230px;
    width: 230px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
}
#holdingmusicstuff {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
}
.musics {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
`;




var canves = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canves)
canves.id = "canves";
```

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Please include a minimal and reproducible example in your post
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body and remove one set of body tags "*There can be only one <body> element in a document.*"

Comment: @DavePritlove  you can check the website [here](https://arras.io).

Comment: If you load your site an open your developer tools, you will see the document tree ignored internal body tags and treats the whole html as being inside one body element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
let firstBodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
```

I used to just use the 'document.body', I was unaware that the html have two body tags... Make sure you are not creating two body tags by accident. Either way, the code above should create the pointer you look for.

Comment: it doesnt seem to work when i add a child element to it. is there any alternative?

Comment: This can't work. A document can only have one body element. Internal body tags will be ignored by the browser which will treat all the remaining html as being inside a single body beginning at the first body tag.

Comment: @DavePritlove is there a way then for the button to be clickable and remain on the top-left?

Comment: if you can identify an element next to where you want to  insert your element, you might be able to use `element.after()` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) or `element.insertAdjacentElement()` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) to add it there.